# Explain the function

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    total /= len(numbers)
    return total
def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    total = 0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests
    return total
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

print get_letter_grade(lloyd)
```

My question is, how does the function get_letter_grade know to use functions average and get_average if we do not specify them? We input a dictionary as an argument to a function that has no use for them but only for compariisment.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to run - you pass dictionary to the function and then compare it to integer, which throws an error.

Comment: It runs in 2.7 - dict/integer inequalities weren't illegal until 3.X. Still doesn't produce the right output, though.

Comment: im learning in CodeCademy and as i input that code to the editor it runs perfectly and returns an "A".

Comment: i found this same question on other forums but there were no solutions to it.

Comment: Yeah, it _always_ returns an A, even for F students.

Comment: as a gentleman below said it should be - print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd)) -, but i dont get why does it return A if i just input a dic name.

Comment: Because in Python 2.x , dictionary is always greater than int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function get_letter_grade doesn't "know" to use the average and get_average functions.

What you are probably trying to achieve is more something like this:

```
print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
```

or easier to read:

```
# get lloyds average score
lloyd_score = get_average(lloyd)

# get the letter grade corresponding to lloyd's average score
lloyd_letter_grade = get_letter_grade(lloyd_score)

# print that letter grade
print lloyd_letter_grade
```

Comment: stop, it worked, hurrah, u da best, thx! but why does it return A if i input a dictionary for example lloyd?

Comment: can you post the exact code that you are inputting?